# Android GCM: Can we get data as a complete JSON structure?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending a message (POST) to Google GCM server `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send` for sending a push notification to a registered android device. The POST body looks something like this:

```
{
    "registration_ids" : [android_registration_id],
    "data" : {
        "message" : "Hello World!",
        "update" : "You've got a new update",
        "info" : "You've got new information updates too!"
    }
}
```

Suppose that I don't know what all key-value pairs are being sent to me (gcm registered android app) in the "data" field and I want to enumerate and print them, can I extract the fields in "data" as a JSON structure?

For e.g. In the above example, I need the following as a JSON object:

```
{
    "message" : "Hello World!",
    "update" : "You've got a new update",
    "info" : "You've got new information updates too!"
}
```

Comment: as i know GCM is sending the data capsulated in Bundle object, but you can try to send key - value structured data and as value put your json. not really sure if it will do the trick.

Comment: I can send the entire JSON as a value to suppose "json_structure" as you said, but I want to make it completely independent for the user, whatever the user passes, I'll make a JSON structure and display key-value pair.

Comment: what role is playing the user in the whole game? you are going to take the response and show it to the user.

Comment: sorry, let me rephrase it, the server passes arbitrary data, the user has to view that data. I just need to know if there is a way to dump the entire "data" value in a JSON structure, I'll iterate over key value pairs and display them.

Comment: you need to show the user the single parts of the whole json string as i understand like only Hello World from your example. So as I know from server side if you send a json string via GCM, android device will receive it as Bundle and you have to know the key to get the value. You can try to send a json within a json as value, not sure if it will work, but that's the only idea which I have, in case you don't know the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
Iterator<String> it = data.keySet().iterator();
String key;
String value;
while(it.hasNext()) {
    key = it.next();
    value = data.getString(key);
}
```

Try this. Using key and value you can construct initial json.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonBodyOfTheResponse);

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
    .
    .
    . }
```